# No JDK specified for module 'app' Android Studio - Mac

Tags: java, android-studio

Where can I select the JDK to fix the error?
I don't see any drop down list?
OS: MAC Catalina

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, I downloaded the minimum SDK version and it worked fine for me.

1. Go to Tools > SDK Manager [image: Tools > SDK Manager]
2. And then Add the minimum SDK version required for the project. I had Android 10 as Minimum SDK, so choose your carefully. [image: Add the minimum SDK]